# Decoding a redirect url - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url

I'd like to use the URI or CGI libraries to get the path from the query part of this url.  In other words, just: '/scouting/amateur'.  Is this possible or do I need to use regexp?

http://10.241.180.63:3149/login?redirect_path=http%3A%2F%2F10.241.180.63%3A3149%2Fscouting%2Famateur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion with Ruby built-ins (if designing a method, you might want to implement some error handling).

```
require 'uri'

query = URI("http://10.241.180.63:3149/login?redirect_path=http%3A%2F%2F10.241.180.63%3A3149%2Fscouting%2Famateur").query

path = URI(URI.decode(query).split('=')[1]).path
```

You may find the gem [uri-query_params](https://github.com/postmodern/uri-query_params#examples) helpful / more elegant (it will decode query params automatically). E.g.

```
require 'uri/query_params'

uri = URI("http://10.241.180.63:3149/login?redirect_path=http%3A%2F%2F10.241.180.63%3A3149%2Fscouting%2Famateur")

URI(uri.query_params["redirect_path"]).path
```

Comment: This one will do: path = URI(URI.decode(query).split('=')[1]).path.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can upvote or select answer as "accepted." :)

Comment: What I needed the path and query?  ie. redirect_path=http%3A%2F%2Fpro2.bloombergsportspro.com%2Fplayer_development%2Fgame_reports%3FstartDate%3D2015-06-01%26endDate%3D2015-06-30

Comment: Got it.  `path = URI(URI.decode(query).split('redirect_path=')[1]).request_uri`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
url = URI.parse('http:://10.241.180.63:3149/login?redirect_path=http%3A%2F%2F10.241.180.63%3A3149%2Fscouting%2Famateur')

redirect_path = u.opaque.split("redirect_path=").last
# redirect_path is now {"redirect_path"=>["http://10.241.180.63:3149/scouting/amateur"]}

result = redirect_path.split("/").last(2).join("/")
# result = 'scouting/amateur'
```